# How does Office Online Server understand the licence status of a request?

Tags: ms-wopi

When we implement a WOPI Host, how does the WOPI Client understand the licence status of a request?

I have not seen anything in the documentation where the request conveys the office365 ID of the users.

My client is failing when the iFrame loads and I'm wondering if it is due to licence information improperly conveyed to host.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, sharing for benefit of who wants to know.

> When Office Online is loaded for business users, it will check that the user is signed in with an Office 365 business account. If the user is not signed in, they’ll be prompted to sign in.

https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/business.html